# Is it wise to repost or amend my question if there is no activity on them?

Tags: discussion, support

I overlooked some other questions here and saw that duplicating questions resulted in a negative reputation.

I do not want to sound obnoxious to the community by reposting questions (I never had) but given the scenario of my issue is it wise to?

I want to hear your opinion.

**When should I repost it if I haven't found a solution, should I flag it or should I amend it and post it again?**

Comment: Edit the question to bump it, if you can add something of substance. Otherwise, a bounty. Do not re-post it.

Comment: How do I add a bounty to the question?

Comment: @FryonAlexandra http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Do not repost questions, period.** That will only lead to them being closed as duplicates.

There are two ways to get some more attention to your post:

- Edit it to add some more information about the problem you found in the meantime, this will bump the post to the frontpage. Don't use trivial edits to do that, though.
- Put a bounty on the question.

Flagging is also not appropriate, there is nothing a moderator can do about an unanswered question.

Answer (score 5):

> When should I repost it if I haven't found a solution, should I flag it or should I amend it and post it again?

*Short answer*: You should **never** repost a question.

*Longer answer*:

There are multiple ways to get your question above in the list: (sorted by best)

1. StackOverflow has a great [bounty feature](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to provide an easy to use system for bumping questions.
2. You can also edit your question, this will cause the question to get on the homepage
3. Mr. Community (our bot) is able to bump questions of which he thinks deserives some attention.

---

Duplicated Questions and Flagging are tools to remove bad questions from the site, this should not be used in cases like this.